# Shiny App not reacting when clicking points in R

Tags: shiny, reactive

I am trying now since days to get my Shiny App working so that when I move my mouse to certain points in the plot they are displayed in a table but unfortunately it is not working. 
I am not sure what I am doing wrong, can you help me?

border <- table$A < 0.03

ui <- fluidPage(
        mainPanel(
            plotOutput("Plot",click="plot_click"),
            tableOutput("HitSpots")
    ) 
)

server <- function(input, output){

```
output$Plot <- renderPlot({ 
    ggplot(table,aes(x=table$A, y=table$B), colour=border)) +
        geom_point() 
})
```

hit <- reactive({
        nearPoints(table, input$plot_click)
    })

```
output$HitSpots <- renderTable({
   hit()
}
```

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems with your parentheses. But the main problem is that you do `ggplot(table, aes(x=table$A, y=table$B))`, and then `nearpoints` is looking for columns named `table$A` and `table$B`. Do `ggplot(table, aes(x=A, y=B))` instead.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

table <- data.frame(
  A = c(1,2,3),
  B = c(3,2,1)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("Plot", click="plot_click"), 
    tableOutput("HitSpots")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){

  output$Plot <- renderPlot({ 
    ggplot(table, aes(x=A, y=B)) + geom_point() 
  })

  hit <- reactive({ nearPoints(table, input$plot_click) })

  output$HitSpots <- renderTable({
    hit()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: @Bine Glad to help. Could you please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)? So that your question is listed in the answered questions.

Comment: great answer! can you please take a look at this question if you have some time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66699881/interactive-plots-in-r