# Interactive Plots in R

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, shiny, plotly

Using the plotly library, I made the following plot in R:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(var1 = rnorm(1000,10,10),
                   var2 = rnorm(1000,5,5))

df <- df %>% mutate(var3 = ifelse(var1 <= 5 & var2 <= 5, "a", ifelse(var1 <= 10 & var2 <= 10, "b", "c"))) 


plot = df %>%
  ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=var1, y= var2, color= var3))


ggplotly(plot)
```

[image]

This is a simple scatter plot - two random variables are generated, and then the colors of the points are decided by some criteria (e.g. if var1 and var2 are between certain ranges).

From here, I could also summary statistics:

```
df$var3 = as.factor(df$var3)
summary = df %>%
    group_by(var3) %>%
    summarize(Mean_var1 = mean(var1), Mean_var2 = mean(var2), count=n())

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  var3  Mean_var1 Mean_var2 count
* <fct>     <dbl>     <dbl> <int>
1 a         -1.70     0.946   158
2 b          4.68     4.94    260
3 c         15.8      6.49    582
```

My question: is it possible to add some buttons to this plot which would allow the user to color the points based on custom choices? E.g. something like this :

[image]

Now, the user can type in any range they want - and the color of the points change, and the some summary statistics are generated.

Can someone please show me how to do this in R?

I had this idea - first I would create this massive table that would create all possible range combinations of "var1" and "var2":

```
vec1 <- c(-20:40,1)
vec2 <-  c(-20:40,1)


a <- expand.grid(vec1, vec2)

for (i in seq_along(vec1)) { 
    for (j in seq_along(vec2)) {

df <- df %>% mutate(var3 = ifelse(var1 <= i & var2 <= i, "a", ifelse(var1 <= j & j <= 10, "b", "c"))) 

}

}
```

Then, depending on which ranges the user wants - an SQL style statement isolate the rows from this massive table corresponding to those ranges :

```
custom_df = df[df$var1 > -20 & df$var1 <10 & df$var1 > -20 & df$var2 <10 , ]
```

Then, an individual grap would be made for "custom_df" and summary statistics would also be recorded for "custom_df":

```
summary = custom_df %>%
    group_by(var3) %>%
    summarize(Mean_var1 = mean(var1), Mean_var2 = mean(var2), count=n())
```

But I am not sure how to neatly and efficiently do this in R.

[image]

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a solution in `shiny`?

Comment: Originally I was trying to only solve this using plotly - but now I think this is only possible to solve using shiny. I am trying to learn some basic shiny from this website (https://mastering-shiny.org/action-dynamic.html). What do you suggest?

Comment: Have you checked on this [site](https://plotly-r.com/preface.html)  it may give you more ideas of interactive plots

Comment: This may require some effort and that could be the reason there are no answers yet.  If you didn't get an answer, an option is also to raise a small bounty to get more people look into it

Comment: I will raise a bounty when i can. In the mean time, i am trying to learn more shiny

Comment: Those links are really useful.  If you learn it by yourself, it would help you a lot in answering those

Comment: Right now, I am trying to adapt the code from your previous answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49473915/r-how-do-i-use-selectinput-in-shiny-to-change-the-x-and-fill-variables-in-a-gg ) to my question .

Comment: @akrun: i have now put a bounty on this question

Comment: thanks, it may get more attention now

Comment: thank you - i hope it does as well

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have built a small shiny app to perform most of your requirements.  Based on your pre-defined large dataframe `df`, user can define the following:

1. Choose the minimum and maximum value for variables `var1` and `var2`.
2. Choose criteria to define the variable `var3`, which is used to display different colors of data points.  This is a range now.
3. Save plot as a HTML file.
4. Summary stats displayed as a table.

You can define further options to provide the user the option to choose color and so on.  For that perhaps you should google on how to use `scale_color_manual()`.

**Update:** Added user option to choose red and green color based on var1 and var2 range values.

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

### define a large df
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(var1 = rnorm(1000,10,10),
                 var2 = rnorm(1000,15,15))

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(p("My First Test App", style = "color:red")),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      p("Choose Variable limits"),

      # Horizontal line ----
      tags$hr(),
      uiOutput("var1a"), uiOutput("var1b"),
      uiOutput("var2a"), uiOutput("var2b"),
      uiOutput("criteria")

    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("summary"), br(),
      plotlyOutput("plot"),
      br(), br(), br(),
      uiOutput("saveplotbtn")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output$var1a <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      numericInput("var11", "Variable 1 min",
                  min = min(df$var1), max = max(df$var1), value = min(df$var1))
    )
  })
  output$var1b <- renderUI({
    if (is.null(input$var11)){
      low1 <- min(df$var1)
    }else low1 <- max(min(df$var1),input$var11)  ## cannot be lower than var 1 minimum
    tagList(
      numericInput("var12", "Variable 1 max", min = low1, max = max(df$var1), value = max(df$var1))
    )
  })
  
  output$var2a <- renderUI({
    tagList(
      numericInput("var21", "Variable 2 min",
                   min = min(df$var2), max = max(df$var2), value = min(df$var2))
    )
  })
  output$var2b <- renderUI({
    if (is.null(input$var21)){
      low2 <- min(df$var2)
    }else low2 <- max(min(df$var2),input$var21)  ## cannot be lower than var 2 minimum
    tagList(
      numericInput("var22", "Variable 2 max", min = low2, max = max(df$var2), value = max(df$var2))
    )
  })
  
  output$criteria <- renderUI({
    req(input$var11,input$var12,input$var21,input$var22)
        
    tagList(
      sliderInput("crit11", "Variable 1 red color range:",
                  min = -10, max = 0, value = c(-10,0)),
      sliderInput("crit12", "Variable 2 red color range:",
                  min = -25, max = 0, value = c(-25,0)),
      sliderInput("crit21", "Variable 1 green color range:",
                  min = 0.1, max = 10, value = c(0.1,10)),
      sliderInput("crit22", "Variable 2 green color range:",
                  min = 0.1, max = 20, value = c(0.1,20))
    )

  })
  
  dat <- reactive({
    req(input$crit11,input$crit12,input$crit21,input$crit22)
    
    df <- df %>% filter(between(var1, input$var11, input$var12)) %>% 
                 filter(between(var2, input$var21, input$var22))
    
    # df1 <- df %>% mutate(var3 = ifelse(var1 <= i & var2 <= i, "a", ifelse(var1 <= j & var2 <= j , "b", "c")))
    
    df1 <- df %>% mutate(var3 = ifelse(between(var1, input$crit11[1], input$crit11[2]) & between(var2, input$crit12[1], input$crit12[2]), "a",
                                       ifelse(between(var1, input$crit21[1], input$crit21[2]) & between(var2, input$crit22[1], input$crit22[2]), "b", "c")))
    
  })
  
  summari <- reactive({
    req(dat())
    df1 <- dat()
    df1$var3 = as.factor(df1$var3)
    summary = df1 %>%
      group_by(var3) %>%
      dplyr::summarize(Mean_var1 = mean(var1), Mean_var2 = mean(var2), count=n())
  })
  
  output$summary <- renderDT(summari())
  
  rv <- reactiveValues()
  
  observe({
    req(dat())
    p <- ggplot(data=dat()) + geom_point(aes(x=var1, y= var2, color= var3))
    pp <- ggplotly(p)
    rv$plot <- pp
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    rv$plot
  })
  
  output$saveplotbtn <-  renderUI({
    div(style="display: block; padding: 5px 350px 5px 50px;",
        downloadBttn("saveHTML",
                     HTML("HTML"),
                     style = "fill",
                     color = "default",
                     size = "lg",
                     block = TRUE,
                     no_outline = TRUE
        ) )
  })
  
  output$saveHTML <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("myplot", Sys.Date(), ".html", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(rv$plot), file, selfcontained = TRUE)  ## self-contained
    }
  )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! I am thinking of replacing "criteria 1" and "criteria 2" with a "variable 3 range" instead . is it possible to have another box that records the summary statistics for each range combination? I can not thank you enough for your help!

Comment: is it possible to replace the sliders with a text box? can the final result be saved as a html file?

Comment: If the answer satisfies you, please accept it by clicking the check mark. If you haven’t done so, you should also consider upvoting this solution as well.

Comment: @iamericfletcher : i have upvoted the solution. there are a few things that I am trying to fix from this solution (I mentioned them in the comments). thank you!

Comment: thank you for all your help! i find myself a bit confused on how to set the ranges correctly. is it possible to simplify this, such as giving the user an option to color points like this : e.g. color points red if var1 between (-10,0) and var2 between (-25,0) - color points green if var1 between (0.1, 10) and var2 between (0.1,20), and color all remaining points blue? thank you again for all your help

Comment: @stats555, It is considered polite to accept an answer that has answered your OP. This helps others who are looking for a solution for the same/similar query. Furthermore, people may be willing to help you in your future queries.

Comment: sorry - i have accepted it now. I thought I had already clicked "accept". my appologies