# R Shiny Produces Empty Outputs

Tags: r, shiny, data-visualization, interactive

I am following the examples from this website here on R shiny: https://mastering-shiny.org/action-graphics.html

I copied and pasted the following code from the website:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("height", "height", min = 100, max = 500, value = 250),
  sliderInput("width", "width", min = 100, max = 500, value = 250),
  plotOutput("plot", width = 250, height = 250)
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot(
    width = function() input$width,
    height = function() input$height,
    res = 96,
    {
      plot(rnorm(20), rnorm(20))
    }
  )
}
```

But this produces no output at all.

According to the website, this should produce a similar output:

[image]
But the code I ran produces no output at all.

Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It is giving me the output based on the code.  Can you try on a fresh R session

Comment: Have you run the command `shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)` at the end

Comment: Thank you! this seems to have fixed the problem!

Comment: can you please take a look at this question if you have some time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66699881/interactive-plots-in-r thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to execute the ui, server in `shinyApp`

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! I will press the "check mark" as soon as I can (it says I have to wait 8 minutes before I can click the green check mark)

Comment: can you please take a look at this question if you have some time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66699881/interactive-plots-in-r thank you for all your help!